# R - mutate based on previous values in the same column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021),
                 growth = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.08, 0.06),
                 size = c(100, NA, NA, NA))

  year growth size
1 2018   0.05  100
2 2019   0.10   NA
3 2020   0.08   NA
4 2021   0.06   NA
```

I have size for year `2018` and growth rates for subsequent years. My goal is to calculate size for each subsequent year as `size[i] = size[i-1] * (1 + growth[i])`. I can do it with a for loop:

```
for (i in (2:nrow(df))) {
  df$size[i] <- df$size[i-1] * (1 + df$growth[i]) 
}

  year growth    size
1 2018   0.05 100.000
2 2019   0.10 110.000
3 2020   0.08 118.800
4 2021   0.06 125.928
```

But I cannot find a `dplyr` way of doing the same thing, with `mutate` for example. Hoping to hear your ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first value of `size` is effectively a multiplicative constant for the rest of the column, we can just use the `cumprod` (cumulative product) of `1 + growth` to get the factor by which to multiply `size[1]` to fill the rest of the `size` column.

The slight complication is that your algorithm has to ignore the first value of `growth`. We can get round this by using a combination of `lead` and `lag`.

The following therefore works without having to use loops.

```r
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, size = lag(size[1] * cumprod(lead(growth + 1)), default = size[1]))

#>   year growth    size
#> 1 2018   0.05 100.000
#> 2 2019   0.10 110.000
#> 3 2020   0.08 118.800
#> 4 2021   0.06 125.928
```

Comment: This is working great on my example. How can this be adjusted if I want to run this for a grouped dataframe? For example: `df <- data.frame(country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), year = c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), growth = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.08, 0.06, 0.02, 0.08, 0.04, 0.04), size = c(100, NA, NA, NA, 200, NA, NA, NA)) %>% group_by(country)`?

Comment: @denisafonin it should still work with grouped data frames. It certainly seems to give the expected result with the data frame you have included in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `purrr::reduce`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(year = c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021),
                 growth = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.08, 0.06),
                 size = c(100, NA, NA, NA))

reduce(2:nrow(df), function(x,y) 
  {x$size[y] <- x$size[y-1]*(1+x$growth[y]); x}, .init=df)
#>   year growth    size
#> 1 2018   0.05 100.000
#> 2 2019   0.10 110.000
#> 3 2020   0.08 118.800
#> 4 2021   0.06 125.928
```